# Android List item XML layout

Tags: xml, listview, android-layout, layout

I have an XML to display items in the ListView. For some reason it looks like that:

[image]

I tried I think everything to fix it - paddings, different layout_width and layout_height... It still looks like this, sometimes even worse. Best case scenario was when I changed the title to textAppearanceSmall. But then I can barely see it. I also want to make the date and time texts below the title a bit bigger, and the pencil icon to be vertically aligned.

Here's the XML code of the item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icoNoteItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/note_item_edit_icon_Description"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noteTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noteTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noteDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="8sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where's the problem here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting property "android:layout_height" of second LinearLayout in the code you have given to "wrap_content" will do. I have run the program and its working fine after this change.